# CXF : Elasticsearch Java API

Tags: spring, web-services, elasticsearch, cxf, elastic-stack

When using Elasticsearh Java API inside Servlet in Tomcat, getting "org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available"

I am trying to create a simple REST API using cxf.

It will do following work -

1. will read some records from Elasticsearch cluster(using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html).
2. Return the return the result as Json.

When I heat the url = "http://localhost:8080/aee-services/sequence/?txID=5f64f331-63c9-485d-9018-6872b1cf5f91"

I am getting this

```
/sequence : txId = 5f64f331-63c9-485d-9018-6872b1cf5f91




no modules loaded
loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.ReindexPlugin]
loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.join.ParentJoinPlugin]
loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorPlugin]
loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.script.mustache.MustachePlugin]
loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty3Plugin]
loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
19:09:09.147 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor@1464d94b
19:09:09.147 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OneWayProcessorInterceptor@168896e2
19:09:09.148 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor@2494bbf9
19:09:09.148 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.transport.https.CertConstraintsInterceptor@4e848932
19:09:09.164 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] WARN  o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Application {http://services.aee.onap.amdocs.com/}RestServer has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{tIRObbGrQ3KLmv0v4OL4ag}{10.247.83.8}{10.247.83.8:9300}]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:163) ~[cxf-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:129) ~[cxf-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:200) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[cxf-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) ~[cxf-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:223) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:197) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:149) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:290) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:214) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:625) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1372) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.0.M22]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{tIRObbGrQ3KLmv0v4OL4ag}{10.247.83.8}{10.247.83.8:9300}]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:347) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:245) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:363) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:408) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:80) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:54) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.openecomp.sequence.elastic.data.ElasticDataSourceRetriveRecords.getLogRecords(ElasticDataSourceRetriveRecords.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.amdocs.onap.aee.services.RestServer.getSequenceById(RestServer.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:181) ~[cxf-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:97) ~[cxf-core-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
19:09:09.170 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor@54b8545c to phase prepare-send
19:09:09.170 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSDefaultFaultOutInterceptor@28d9d97 to phase marshal
19:09:09.170 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@48c00d4 was created. Current flow:
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor]
  marshal [JAXRSDefaultFaultOutInterceptor]
```

My 
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <display-name>onap-aee-services</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/aeeserver-beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

-beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs 
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />

    <jaxrs:server id="sequence" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <bean class="com.aee.services.RestServer" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>

</beans>
```

And REST request handler class

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHits;
import org.elasticsearch.search.sort.SortOrder;
import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient;
import org.openecomp.sequence.SequenceGenerator;
import org.openecomp.sequence.elastic.data.ElasticDataSourceRetriveRecords;
import org.openecomp.sequence.elastic.data.LogRecord;
import org.openecomp.sequence.impl.SequenceGeneratorImpl;
import org.openecomp.sequence.json.SequenceResponse;

public class RestServer {

    @GET
    @Path("/sequence")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public SequenceResponse getSequenceById(@QueryParam("txID") final String txId) {

        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n/sequence : txId = " + txId + "\n\n\n\n");

        org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("client.transport.sniff", true)
                .put("cluster.name", "onap-cluster").build();

        TransportClient client = null;
        try {
            client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
                    .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("10.247.83.8"), 9300))
                    .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("10.247.83.8"), 9300));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // on shutdown

        String[] mdcs = { "PartnerName", "Component", "loglevel", "Timestamp", "Thread", "LogType", "BeginTimestamp",
                "EndTimestamp" };
        String[] mdcsexclude = { "message", "@timestamp", "@version", "beat" };

        SearchResponse response1 = client.prepareSearch("onaplogs*").addSort("Timestamp", SortOrder.ASC).setFrom(0)
                .setSize(100).setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("RequestId", txId))
                .setFetchSource(mdcs, mdcsexclude).execute().actionGet();

        SearchHits hits = response1.getHits();
        List<LogRecord> logs = new ArrayList<LogRecord>();

        System.out.println(
                "totalHits" + response1.getHits().getTotalHits() + "hitlenght" + response1.getHits().getHits().length);

        SequenceResponse sequenceResponse = null;

        return sequenceResponse;
    }
}
```

pom.xm

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.amdocs.onap.aee.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>onap-aee-services</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <jackson.version>1.8.6</jackson.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Please correct me where I am wrong

**Can we use Elasticsearch Java API inside Servlen Container?**

Note when I am testing using J4Unit test case it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Plz ensure that the cluster name you have provided in the transport client (onap-cluster) matches with the actual cluster name.

Also any reason for adding the same ip (10.247.83.8) twice?